# Splitting a float to two simple integers?

Tags: c, floating-point

I'm trying to implement a c function that does the following:

input:

```
float f= 8.947563;
```

output:

```
uint32_t o1 = 8;
uint32_t o2 = 947563;
```

I want to store each of these outcomes in a specific register.

I've found some solutions like modf function but it doesn't really solve my problem because it's o2 will be 0.947563 instead of 947563.
Additionally, the number of digits after the fraction can differ according to the user input so I can't simply set a rule to multiply 0.947563 by 1000000 for example because it won't work for numbers with bigger fractions like 8.947556333.

Any idea how to solve this issue?
Thanks.

Comment: One problem is that a floating point number doesn't *have* a specific number of decimal places. It is stored in binary format, unless you store as a string.

Comment: Floats are not precise, so decide how many digits after the fractio  you want to represent and multiplie with the corresponding tenth power.

Comment: Do you get your input as decimal string or as binary floating point? If as a string, you could skip conversion to float altogether and avoid conversion inaccuracies.

Comment: The maximum number of digits you could keep, based on your choice of a uint32 for the o2 variable is 9,

Comment: I get my code as an integer numerator and integer denomenator. I can skip the conversion to float part but how to handle it then?

Comment: As a matter of interest, how do you want the number 1.02 to be split? What is the real problem you want to solve?

Comment: acually the float value is time information. I want to store the seconds (1) in a register, and the nanoseconds (02) in another register each of the registers is 32 bits

Comment: In that case you should be working with `double` and not with `float`.

Comment: can you answer the question with a simple code so I can get your point completely please?

Comment: @ʎəʞo uɐɪ do you mean a multiplication by 10^9 always works in my case?

Comment: Like this: `o1 = (uint32_t)f; o2 = (uint32_t)round(fmod(f, 1.0) * 1000000000.0);`

Comment: If you you want to store the number of whole nanoseconds then you can always just multiply 1e9, the number of decimals won't matter. As a side note a float only has 7 (ie less than 9) decimal digits of precision (including the the digits before the decimal point)

Comment: If `f` is represented as 32-bit IEEE 754 binary floating point, its value is `8.94756317138671875`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at some floating point examples:

```
1.5
0x3FC00000
0 01111111 10000000000000000000000
1.10000000000000000000000<<0
1.10000000000000000000000

1.8
0x3FE66666
0 01111111 11001100110011001100110
1.10000000000000000000000<<0
1.10000000000000000000000

2.1
0x40066666
0 10000000 00001100110011001100110
1.00001100110011001100110<<1
10.0001100110011001100110

12.3456
0x41458794
0 10000010 10001011000011110010100
1.10001011000011110010100<<3
1100.01011000011110010100
```

So what is it you want to end up with?

12.3456
1100.01011000011110010100
Your two uint32_ts are 0b1100 and 0b01011000011110010100, the former is in a form you desire but the latter?  Your example is in decimal which of course has nothing to do with floating point numbers on computers.

Your number 8.947563

```
0x410F2938
0 10000010 00011110010100100111000
1.00011110010100100111000<<3
1000.11110010100100111000

f = 8.947563
o1 = 1000
o2 = 00000000000011100111010101101011
```

but

```
11110010100100111000
11100111010101101011
```

are not equal.  The former is the fraction, so some manipulation is required.

```
11110010100100111000/100000000000000000000*11110100001001000000
```

but

```
0xF2938 * 0xF4240
```

does not fit in a 32 bit so we have to step this up to 64 bit.

```
0000000000000000000000001110011101010110101100101011111000000000/100000000000000000000
```

and that is where o2 comes from when you do the base 10 math

```
1110011101010110101100101011111
11100111010101101011
```

could have been done 32 bit

```
0xF293*0xF424
11100111010101100011100010101100
```

and cut off the top 20 bits you get the 947563 o2

```
11100111010101100011100010101100
11100111010101101011
```

So if you always want 6 digits then take the fraction times 1000000 and trim off the right number of bits off the bottom.  for single the mantissa starts off as 23 bits, for your number the exponent was 3 so 20 bits were left in the mantissa for the fraction.  The above cheats some you would want to adjust these numbers to a known alignment just as you would when doing normal floating point math, for example

```
0xF2938000*0xF4240000;
```

gives

```
1110011101010110101100101011111000000000000000000000000000000000
```

We chop the top 32 bits off:

```
11100111010101101011001010111110
```

then take the top 20 bits:

```
11100111010101101011 result
11100111010101101011 o2
```

0xF2938 * 0xF4240 was equally fine 0xF293*0xF424 could have given a different result than the desired.

If that's what you want though, 6 digits in decimal then just do this:

```
   double x, y, z;
   uint32_t a,b;

   x = 8.947563;
   y = modf(x, &z);
   a = z;
   b = y*1000000.0;
   printf("%u %u\n",a,b);
```

which gives:

```
8 947563
```

I'll let you sort out negative numbers.

Answer (score 3):

The function `modff` breaks a `float` into integral and fractional parts (`modf` for `double`). If you need to convert `.947563f` to the integer `947563`, you'll have to do some manner of trick.

One way which is generic, is to convert the float literal to a string and then parse it. Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int modff_int (const char* value, int* iptr)
{
  int fractional;
  sscanf(value, "%d.%d", &fractional, iptr);
  return fractional;
}

#define FLOAT_TO_STR(f) #f  // simplified version that only works with float literals


int main (void)
{
  int integral;
  const char* str = FLOAT_TO_STR(8.947563f);
  int fractional = modff_int(str, &integral);

  printf("Integral:   %d\n", integral);
  printf("Fractional: %d\n", fractional);
}
```

This is however significantly slower than to simply multiply the float `.947563f` by a constant.

Comment: Since latter part is time of nanoseconds, there needs to be additional code to handle the different amount of input digits.

Answer (score 2):

As you have now said that the value is seconds with a nanosecond resolution you need to remove the integer part and keep that as o1, then multiply by 1E9, add 0.5 and then take the integer part of that as o2. The adding of 0.5 is to round off to the nearest nanosecond rather than truncating down.
Note that the variable `f` should be a `double` not a `float` because a `float` can only store around 7 significant digits.

```
#define TEN_POWER_9 ((double)(1e9))    

o1 = int(f) ;
o2 = int(((f - (double)o1) * TEN_POWER_9) + 0.5) ;
```

Comment: -   10E9 is a fixed number in all cases so if the fraction is less than 9 digits the rest will be filled by 0's right?
-   why adding 0.5? 
thanks

Comment: Represented in decimal the less significant digits will be zeros, in binary, who knows.  You are dealing with a binary representation of a floating point quantity so the decimal representation will be inexact and not limit at a certain number of digits.

Comment: `int(((f - (double)o1) * TEN_POWER_9) + 0.5) ;` does not appear to be valid C.  The approach to rounding failes various corner cases.  Consider `lround()` family.

Answer (score -1):

Usually I'm not working with c so i don't know if there's a proper way to do what you want. But what if you convert your float into a string and split them at the point and convert both back to an integer or long or what ever you want. I know that sounds not great but I think that could work.

Comment: Code example can help.